# change input on a MAG(LB2006AFW) monitor

Tags: display

I have 3 computers connected with a single MAG monitor model LB2006AFW.
I want to switch between them with a button press and not through the menu.
Does any one know how to do that? If not then how to do that on a diffrent MAG model?

Please don't advise me to use a KVM as I am already using one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

You need to press the Auto+Input button togther(Took me a few times to make it work because it has to be toghthrr).

Not the best they could have done but it will do.